# What level of support is legally required for off-the-shelf software?

Tags: software, customer-service

When writing and selling off-the-shelf software, there can be warranty requirements for security updates and functional bugfixes. But are there legal requirements to offer support that goes beyond that – especially help desk style support¹? Is it O.K. to only offer paid support?

What are the differences between the markets in EU, US and others?

<sub>¹ To minimize the need for individual support, good documentation and a user friendly interface of course help a lot. But that might not always be sufficient for all clients and all use cases.</sub>

Comment: In general, market considerations probably govern this more than legal requirements, and a general discussion is about as far as it can go in this forum. I suspect that the general answer is that you can offer whatever support you want to, or not, as long as it's laid out clearly in the license agreement. Since you will want a lawyer to write that agreement (and advise on many other questions, such as privacy concerns) you should probably ask these questions of your lawyer.

Comment: @phoog Good advice. We're in a phase where we evaluate if the project is worth pursuing (hence the question what we have to take into account beyond development and marketing). The details are still in the dark. There's no project budget yet and consequently no lawyer involved.

Comment: It might be a good idea to make that clearer in the question, since questions asking for individualized legal advice are off topic here.  A more general question about what the law requires should be okay, however, especially in the context of trying to evaluate potential business models at an early stage of development.

Comment: *"Is it O.K. to only offer paid support?"* - In the US, Cisco (iOS operating system) and Sun (Solaris operating system) have made a fortune off selling defective software and then charging for the patches to fix it. Microsoft (Windows operating system) does it too, to a lesser extent. Not sure about others like IBM (AIX operating system).

Answer (score 1):

In Australia, services sold, hired or leased for less than $40,000 (or for any amount if they are normally bought for household or personal use) must comply with Australian Consumer Law with respect to [Consumer Guarantees](https://www.accc.gov.au/consumers/consumer-rights-guarantees/consumer-guarantees) - this would cover most software products except for bespoke high-end business applications.

In [Australian Competition and Consumer Commission v Valve Corporation (No 3) [ 2016] FCA 196 (24 March 2016)](http://www.austlii.edu.au/cgi-bin/sinodisp/au/cases/cth/FCA/2016/196.html?stem=0&synonyms=0&query=title(%222016%20FCA%20196%22)), the Federal Court has held that software is a "product" within the meaning of ACL.

> **Products** must be of acceptable quality, that is:
>
> - safe, lasting, with no faults
> - do all the things someone would normally expect them to do
> - be fit for the purpose the business told you it would be fit for and for any purpose that you made known to the business before purchasing
> - meet any extra promises made about performance, condition and quality, such as life time guarantees and money back offers
> - have spare parts and repair facilities available for a reasonable time after purchase unless you were told otherwise.

Among other, less relevant, things. Also:

> Acceptable quality takes into account what would normally be expected for the type of product and cost.

Whether this extends to providing free customer support and to what extent will depend on the particular software.